# To store cat output into an array - shell script

Tags: shell

How do I store into an array each line of cat command output ?
E.g if 
cat /daemon is giving me

```
11.11.11-1

22.22.22-2

33.33.33-3

44.44.44-4
```

then how do I store the output into an array using shell script and check if "11.11.11-1" is present in that array in an single if condition (but not inside an iteration)?

Answer (score 0):

Using [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) :

```
$ cat file.txt | readarray arr
$ echo "${arr[@]}"
$ echo "${arr[2]}"
```

See :

```
help readarray
```

For the second requirement :

> check if "11.11.11-1" is present in that array in an single if condition (but not inside an iteration)?

I'm afraid that's not possible in shell, but OK in Perl by example.

**Edit**:  If you want to copy an array through iteration :

```
for i in "${arr[@]}"; do
    arr2[1]=$[arr[i}}
done
```

Comment: I already got this read in an array using for loop, Could you help me on but how can i put back each element I have read from an array into another array through iteration ?Like in first iteration I read 11.11.11-1 and I need to put it into another array in index 1
Thanks !